# Remove duplicate images from flexslider product slider

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a view with Flexslider module with some product fields as `product_image`, `product_title` and `category_name`

the result i got is something like this

[image]

and my view is

[image]

the issue is for every product there are more than one image in the `products` table( i needed this for other purpose) but in this slider depending on the number of images products are repeating (creating duplicates) you can see in the slider above.

can anyone help me to solve this issue. I don't want any duplicate products in this slider.

Thanks in advance

Comment: May i know why this has been downvoted? It will be useful if you mention that in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. Remove reference to taxonomy term because it can couse duplicate rows. Instead use "Category field name".
Next in your Product_image field on tab "multiple field settings" check "Display all values in the same row" option and display 1 element without separator.